# Dataset times out while query runs immediately

Tags: c#, sql, performance, c#-2.0, tableadapter

I am running a query directly, it is trivial in nature:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[vwUnloadedJobDetailsWithData] WHERE JobId = 36963
```

When I run this from Management studio the query doesn't even take a second.  When I run it from within the table adapter it times out.  I have fixed this multiple times, but the fix is ludicrous.  If I delete the table adapter from my xsd file and recreate it the query time matches that of management studio for about two days, but I have to redeploy which is asinine.

Any insight into what could be causing this would be greatly appreciated.  I've seen another question about this but the solution involving set arithabort on before the query had no effect for me.

Edit: It was asked that I show my code for calling the query.  Now this happens when I go into my xsd file and just do preview data as well, but for sake of clarity, here it is:

```
using (TEAMSConnection connection = new TEAMSConnection())
{  
    connection.OpenConnection();

    _JobDetailsDAO jobDetailDao= new _JobDetailsDAO(connection);
    return jobDetailDao.GetUnloadedJobDetailsByJobId(jobId);

}
```

On disposal of connection the database connection is closed. using this line of code:

```
if (_DBConnection != null && _DBConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    _DBConnection.Close();
```

Edit2: I ran a trace and here are the set options that are being set

set quoted_identifier on
set arithabort off
set numeric_roundabort off
set ansi_warnings on
set ansi_padding on
set ansi_nulls on
set concat_null_yields_null on
set cursor_close_on_commit off
set implicit_transactions off
set language us_english
set dateformat mdy
set datefirst 7
set transaction isolation level read committed

I went and added that to the query that I generated in management studio and it still ran in less than a second.  I even copied the query exactly as in the trace.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[vwUnloadedJobDetailsWithData] WHERE JobID = @JobId',N'@JobId int',@JobId=36963
```

and it is still less than a second return time.  I am so very confused.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: It sounds like you're not closing your db connections, but it's hard to know for sure what's going on because you didn't share the c# code.

Comment: Sorry there isn't much code to share.....as far as closing the connection, they are definitely getting closed.  I will post my query and connection handling around that query if you think it would help.

Answer (score 0):

the most likely scenarion why this would be happening is the difference in SET options between ssms and ado.net. that difference causes (re)building of execution plans that might not be optimal.

Comment: I added the set options, do you see anything that triggers any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, well I could not find any solution that would continue to allow me to use the dataset, so I went straight to using the SqlDataAdapter in code rather than using the auto generated TableAdapters.

According to the trace it performs the exact same query, but so far it works.  It may not in two days, but for now it works it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to think loudly:
Maybe there is a lock caused by another process/person? Is there anybody who updates the same row at the same time? Is there anybody who opens the table from Management studio or Query Analyzer with Open Table feature and plays with the filters? 
Try looking for locks using sp_who2

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

What I'd call parameter sniffing for stored proc. Try the [OPTION (RECOMPILE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714(SQL.90).aspx) hint, so your sent SQL looks like this:

```
exec sp_executesql
    N'SELECT *
         FROM [dbo].[vwUnloadedJobDetailsWithData]
         WHERE JobID = @JobId
         OPTION (RECOMPILE)',
    N'@JobId int',
    @JobId=36963
```

Explanation: When a query plan is produced and cached, it may be a bad, atypical value. Say JobID is usually very selective, but for that one execution it's not. When you run the query the next plan the cached plan is wrong for the next selective JobId. A plan will be recompiled for various reasons, but the value on recompilation matters.

Otherwise, what is the exact datatype of Jobid? If it's smallint, then the column will be converted to int in the parameterised query. When using a constant it will be smallint. Make sure the type is defined correctly: this matters in SQL code.